# How to distribute SQL Server Database to clients

Tags: sql, wpf, database

I have a WPF application that I want to deploy to client PCs via a Setup. My setup application will contain the .Net framework and SQL Server Express 2008 edition and will install these on the client if needed and without user interaction.

Now I need a way to create the database and tables, etc... on the client without any user interaction.

Should I deploy the .MDF .LDF to the client PCs and attach the database to SQL Server Express?

Or should I create a script and run the script on the client to create the database and tables?

Plus, I need to ensure that the app.config settings are correct.

What is the best way to handle distributing a database to the client during a Setup.exe with user interaction?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're deploying a stand-alone application to desktop clients, forcing them to install SQL Server Express is the wrong choice. You're going to run into issues if SQL Server stops working on the client's PC.

You should instead use [SQL Server Compact Edition](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx) (which doesn't require a server to be installed on the client's PC). You can include the database file as part of the installation process with all of the blank tables and everything already created.

Comment: The only problem with this solution is that it is not easy to setup a project to do this, at least for a beginner.